# Java convert ET time to UTC time Oracle DB Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timestamp

We have a column update_date in DB. This Oracle database column of type `TIMESTAMP` is updated with ET time.

When I am in **UTC time** - `19-Oct-2019 4:51 AM`, DB saves this time in **Update_date Column** as `19-Oct-19 00:51 AM`.

I try to convert Update_date to UTC in Java from DB. It's not working. Still, it showing the ET timezone only.

My current system time zone is UTC - `19-Oct-2019 4:51 AM`
DB Saving ET timezone - `19-Oct-2019 00:51 AM`
Convert DB Column(ET timezone) to UTC in Java:  `19-Oct-2019 00:51 AM`
expected output: `19-Oct-2019 4:51 AM`

**Java Code Used not working:**

```
Date fromDate = new Date(2019,10,19,00,51,00); //ET time from DB Update_date column
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa");
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");

gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
System.out.println(gmtFormat.format(fromDate));
```

Comment: What database? What is the data type *exactly* of the column?

Comment: Oracle and timestamp

Comment: Post further details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: From my reading of [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1839), `TIMESTAMP` in Oracle db is equivalent to the standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, and is indeed the wrong type to store a moment, as discussed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58461119/642706) below. You should have used `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.  You will need to [refactor your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_refactoring).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` or even better `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## java.time

This issue has been covered many times on Stack Overflow, so I'll be brief. And you neglected to provide important detail such as what database and what is the data type of the column so I cannot give specific code solution.

To retrieve a moment a database, use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To see that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Note that "ET time" is *not* a time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

For columns of a type akin to the [SQL-standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization) `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, many database adjust inputs to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) before storing. So when retrieved, the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object is likely to be in UTC. But to be sure, simply extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC (if not already in UTC).
```

If your column is of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, you are using the wrong type to track a moment, a specific point on the timeline. You do not know what the time zone of previous stored values was because any provided time zone or offset information is ignored and stripped from all inputs. So you have a mess on your hands. You must [refactor your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_refactoring) to use the correct type. You can try guessing as to the intended time zone, and apply that zone during refactoring, but you would only be guessing.

```
// Extract old value without zone/offset info.
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( oldColumn , LocalDateTime.class ) ;

// Guessing this time zone was originally intended. 
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;

// Arbitrarily apply the time zone that we assume, but do not truly know, was intended when that date-time was originally stored.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;

// Store the new value in a new column.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( newColumn , odt ) ;
```

When complete, delete your old column, or rename to indicate it should no longer be used.

Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) might be able to handle a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). But the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) spec requires support only for `OffsetDateTime`.

[image]